# Web font character 'swapping' on OSX & iOS on a particular website

Tags: html, ios, css, macos, webfonts

I've just seen a very strange issue on a website (http://www.paintnsign.com.au) that I haven't seen since the site was launched over a year ago.  It was previously tested across multiple OSs and browsers and all the fonts rendered correctly.

The site is using a (self hosted) web font (Carnivalee Freakshow) which was converted from a TTF to a web font 'kit' using <strike>[Font Squirrel's Web Font Kit Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)</strike> [Font2Web](http://www.font2web.com)'s Web Font generator.

What I'm seeing now is that, even though the correct font is being loaded, the *letters are all swapped* like a cipher.  For example on the [Bespoke Signwriting page](http://www.paintnsign.com.au/artistic-bespoke-signwriting/), the main heading should read: "MODERN, ARTISTIC, TRADITIONAL & HANDWRITTEN BESPOKE SIGNWRITING" however, it is rendering "OQFGTP,CTVKUVKE, VTCFKVKQOCN, & JCPFYTKVVGP DGURQMG UKIPYTKVKPI".  The underlying generated HTML contains the correct markup:

```
<h2>Modern, Artistic, Traditional &amp; Handwritten Bespoke Signwriting</h2>
```

What's strange is that it is occurring only on all browsers on OSX (Mountain Lion 10.9.5 & El Capitan 10.11.2) and iOS 9.2 (iPad & iPhone).  Everything renders correctly on my Android tablets & phones and also on Chrome on Windows (run in VMWare Fusion).  I ran tests in browsershots.org (Firefox on [Linux](http://browsershots.org/screenshots/d335b35cd8c8070e9754d078bb7e31b4), [Windows](http://browsershots.org/screenshots/d335b35cd8c8070e9754d078bb7e31b4) & [OSX](http://browsershots.org/screenshots/ac3a490f1767982f5cd9ffbe86d62548)) and the font renders correctly in the screenshots.   Incidentally the same issue arises whether I test the site on the production server or on a local dev machine.

This is what I'm seeing across numerous devices at the moment:
[image: Screenshot of website with characters swapping for a particular webfont]

The other web fonts used on the site (hosted at fonts.com) render correctly.

So is anyone else seeing the heading font render incorrectly?  Any ideas why this might be happening?  Is it only OSX / iOS?

**UPDATE:**
So it appears that the original font kit used (generated via Fonts2Web) had some issues - certain files had the characters all shifted. When I switched it for a FontSquirrel generated kit, everything was back to normal.

So I guess the questions now are, why was it rendering properly on some versions OSX and not others?  Has something happened in the last 12 months or so on iOS / OSX to change the preference of font file loaded? Why was it working on other OSs e.g. Android and Windows and also on BrowserShots?

Comment: just to let you know: On my MacOS 10.10.5 the font is rendered correctly in Firefox, Chrome and Safari

Comment: @Johannes - thanks very much for letting me know. Hmmm...

Comment: Just some random thoughts... can you test each of the font files (woff, ttf etc) separately to see if one of them is the culprit? Also, is this font one that happens to be installed on the offending machines locally?

Comment: I'll attempt do that by modifying the code to only include one don't file at a time. Although when I tried to test it with a online font testing web app, it seemed to be possibly influenced by the same underlying problem and all the files seemed to be exhibiting the problem, so it wasn't clear whether the font files were faulty or something on my iOS and OSX devices.

Comment: Interestingly, I was able to open up the site on one of the iOS devices and the headings rendered correctly. Opening it a couple of hours later on the same device, the problem is back

Comment: @MrLister I individually included each font file and it appears that all other font files apart from the original TTF file were problematic.  Looking closer, it appears that the web font kit used was generated via Font2Web's generator, not FontSquirrel as I previously thought.  When I switched it for the FontSquirrel generated kit, everything was back to normal! Yay!  But what is bizarre is that sometime within the last 12 months or something has changed in OSX / iOS in what web font was being used. Maybe TTFs were used before and then recently WOFFs began to be used?